# Understanding AJAX history

Tags: javascript, ajax

I apologize in advance if this is a simple question, but I'm reading about Javascript and AJAX and wanted to understand a little bit more about what led to the importance of AJAX.

Based on my understanding, prior to AJAX, if a web page wanted to modify its content, the user would have to REFRESH / RELOAD the page, which would trigger a HTTP request being sent to the web server.  However, with the advent of AJAX, it is possible for the browser to modify its content WITHOUT the user actually manually refreshing the page - instead, an XMLHttpRequest object could be sent from the browser to the server to retrieve data that updates the web page.  This is probably an oversimplification, but am I correct at a high level?

Comment: Your high-level understanding seems correct. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: Yes it is. But, still SO is not the place to ask

Comment: Yup, you pretty have it.  It is interesting to note that despite it's name, calls do not have to be asynchronous and they use JSON just fine (or perhaps even better).  In addition, it is also interesting that despite Gmail being one of the first truly successful AJAX implementations, it was really microsoft who laid a lot of the pioneer groundwork.  At any rate, this is not a SO appropriate question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, and apologies for putting it on SO - I just felt that this was the best place to have other knowledgable folks confirm if my basic understanding was accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True .

Ajax sends XML request to server and gets the XML Output based on Events.

Ajax by default is Asynchronous (meaning it won't wait for the result to come,but it will be invoked when the result is available).

You can always make it synchronous though.

It is the `callback` function that takes the data and updates :)

You can learn more about callback [here](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for the info on callback!